# SQL Server - Delete Duplicate Rows that based on different rows from another field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, duplicates

i have column and rows in my table as below

```
col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
----------------------------
1     A     1     100   AA
2     B     2     200   BB
3     B     1     100   AA
4     A     2     200   BB
```

i want the final result is

```
col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
----------------------------
1     A     1     100   AA
2     B     2     200   BB
```

OR

```
col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
----------------------------
3     B     1     100   AA
4     A     2     200   BB
```

i want to **delete first and second rows** OR **third and fourth rows** but based on col1, as you can see, their's not same with each other rows except with the col0, because the col0 is primary key. how should i do with sql server express 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE col0 NOT IN ( SELECT MIN(col0) FROM yourTable GROUP BY col1)
```

Comment: yeah, that's working perfect! but, what the impact of that queries if the duplicate rows is thousand?

Comment: What problem do you have? Will it be slow?

Comment: i just feel worried if that queries deleting wrong records haha. anyway thankyou so much for helping @tien

Comment: what i am worried is happening, that queries have delete the wrong records. i was tested it with 16 record that have 4 duplicates each others

Comment: Can you give me your data? I try test.

Comment: where should i send the data for you?

Comment: My email is nntien.nguyen@gmail.com. I will reply as soon as possible.

Comment: i've sent you the data as excel file

Comment: I've sent you a question via email. Can you reply me?

Comment: I've sent you my answer via email. It can work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option for deleting the first pair of duplicate records.  You can assign a row number based on a partition of the four data columns.  Do this in a CTE, and then delete all records from that CTE where the row number is 1.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col2, col3, col4 ORDER BY col0) rn
    FROM yourTable
)
DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Follow the link below for a demo showing that the logic of my CTE is correct.

## Demo

Comment: still not working sir, their delete the same rows. if iam including the col1, it's nothing to delete

Comment: @fannykaunang Sorry I didn't look closely enough at your data.  Just remove `col1` from the partition and it should work.

Comment: there are deleting the duplicate on col2.col3 and col4 but col1 still duplicate sir if i remove the col1 from the partititon

Comment: i think is the partition is not the solution on this

Comment: thanks @tim, i corrected my asumming for the partition on this. know their working good perfect sir. thank you very much!!

Comment: i was tested it sir, it working good with four records that have two duplicates like my original data on this post, but if i put 16 records with four duplicates each other, their delete affected sometimes is different count

Comment: Then use `DELETE FROM cte WHERE rn <> 1` ... this would retain only the first pair.

Comment: yes sir, there are retain only first pair at col2 but ignored the col1 that are important to make the rows have no duplicate

Comment: the result of col1 is = a,b,c,c. it should be a,b,c,d

Comment: @fannykaunang Please stop commenting under my answer, and I have flagged your comments.  Either update your question, or open a new question.